# When adding dynamic html( a button with a modal class associated with it) using $().html(), bootstrap seems to not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

When using datatable to dynamically create a button, which when clicked will display the modal class associated with it.i am able to successfully do so,however the bootstrap seems not to be working.I am using fnRowCallback function of datatable and then creating dynamic button and modal div using jquery html function, $().html

```
$('td:eq(4)', nRow).html('
  <div class="text-center">
     <button class="btn btn-sm btn-flat btn-danger width-150px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm2'+aaData[1]+'">'+aaData[1]+'-Update</button>
  </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModalNorm2'+aaData[1]+'" tabindex="-1"role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2'+aaData[1]+'" aria-        hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                         <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                     </button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title"id="myModalLabel2'+aaData[1]+'">File Service Plan -'+aaData[1]+' -'+aaData[1]+'</h4>
            </div>

      <!-- Modal Body -->

            <div class="modal-body">

                    <form role="form" action="" method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm">
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="box-body">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                             <label>Service ID</label> 
                                                             <input type="text" readonly hidden class="form-control" id="serviceid" name="serviceid" value="'+aaData[1]+'"/>
                                                        </div>

                                                </div>
                                    </div>

                            </div> 
                    </form>
            </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-"data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="SUBMIT">Save Changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
');
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the bootstrap seems not to be working" ?

Comment: can you explain:- `the bootstrap seems not to be working.`?

Comment: Yes sure, the bootstrap classes, .row , .col-md-12 , .form-group they are not adding the margin, padding and etc. for example, col-md-12 should make input use 100% width but it not doing so.

Comment: you are adding that code  for every single row? You should only have only one modal and use event handlers to update the modal just before or just after its shown.

Comment: @Bindrid Yes for now i am doing that only, as of now i do not have clear understanding of how i can bind the data received from datatable's ajax call on to events

Comment: Also, with respect to question i have asked, Datatable formats input textarea etc as per the need to suit for display in a table. What i have done for now is make a separate copy of datatable bootstrap css and javascript and for this page and have edited them to not apply datatable's exclusive formatting to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, you should not put the modal inside your table. You should have a single modal html defined on your form set up for reuse. I put mine at the bottom of my html between the  tag and the  tags.

```
   columnDefs:[{targets:-1, render:function () {
      return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>Show</button>";

    }}],
```

Is all I put in that column then attach a button handler.

You can see my fully functioning code on JSBin http://live.datatables.net/sesabupo/1/edit

This code uses a row button to show the data in a modal or you can select the row and click the details button on the bottom